# Render API Key field in Swagger UI for FastAPI using APIRouter

Tags: python, fastapi, swagger-ui, endpoint, api-key

I am building a FastAPI application, where I want to add in an `authenticate_user` function that will do just that on all endpoints associated with a router. The API Builder looks like this:

```
        self.routers = ApiRouter(config=self.config)
        self.api = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

        # inject api routers
        self.api.include_router(self.routers.router)
```

Where the ApiRouter looks like this:

```
class ApiRouter:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config
        self.router = APIRouter(dependencies=[Depends(self.authenticate_user)])

    async def authenticate_user(self, x_key: Annotated[str, Header()]:
        if x_key not in self.config.API_KEYS:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="X-Key header is invalid")
```

The endpoint that I am expecting to see the API Key showing up in Swagger UI is:

```
@api.post("/my_endpoint", response_model=EndpointResponse, status_code=200)
async def my_endpoint_here(
    request: EndpointRequest = Body(
        ..., exclude=['this', 'that', 'other']
    )
):
```

When running the application and hitting the `/docs` endpoint, the swagger does not have anything to fill out the `x-key` that the `authenticateuser` is expecting. However, if I just add the `authenticateuser` as a `Depends` directly on the api route, then it shows up. This is not a solution I want though, as it then requires alot of code repeating of just adding in the Depends on every endpoint.

Please help!

Tried:

- using ApiKeyHeader from fastapi.security.api_key
- using Security() around it